# Shadow on android button or textview

Tags: java, android

How can i add shadow on a button or textview on android studio to make cool my buttons and text's ??

NOTE: I'm beginner on android development so i don't want to make something that I do not understand

Answer (score 1):

use this sample:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/txt1"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:textSize="14sp"
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:textColor="#ff00ff"
                  android:shadowColor="eeeeee"
                  android:shadowDx="1"
                  android:shadowDy="1"
                  android:shadowRadius="2" />
```